# Importing csv file to R new line issue

Tags: r, csv, import, newline

I have a csv file which has a text field that contains new line character '\n', so i cannot correctly import this file into R. My csv end of line is actually '\r\n' and I want R to use it as end of line, how I can do this?

Thanks

EDIT:

It seems R is ignoring my new line character in some records. An example is:

> data[48,]

```
Var1   Var2   Var3 

 345   blue    N
```

> data[49,]

```
Var1   Var2   Var3

 634    red    N\n821,green,
```

where data[50,] should start with 821,green

I am using allowEscapes=TRUE.

Comment: did you try to use the allowEscapes option in read.table?

Comment: Can you paste a few lines sample of your data file?

Answer (score 1):

In a lot of csv handling implementations, you have to escape fields that have \n and other such codes, usually with quotes or double-quotes. Such as 'this is\nan example'

Comment: I don't really understand. I edited my question, do you think it applies?